# .net core 2.0 not support system.refletion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

NU1202  O package System.Reflection 4.3.0 not support netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). O package System.Reflection 4.3.0 support:
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)

Microsot.ASPNetCore.ALL is not suppported it self.

Someone know how to solve it?

Comment: Not sure about Xamarin, but in my .NET Core 2.0 Web API, I am referencing System.Runtime (4.2.0.0, x64, .NETCoreApp v2.0.0.0) and under this I can access System.Reflection stuff.

Comment: I am not using Xamarin i create a default web application project and the template add a lot of references, and this references use the sistem.reflection 4.3 and the site does not compile and return the error above...